# R drops hours, minutes, and seconds from date

Tags: r, datetime, time, xts

While converting a dataframe to `xts` I realized that there is something wrong with the formatter. Here's an example dataframe:

```
effective_date         price
"1990-01-01"  "100"
"1990-01-02 00:05:00"  "200"
```

This is example output from a package that I use.

Converting this to `xts` is straight-forward

`xts(df["price"], order_by=as.POSIXct(df["effective_date"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

However this errors out, saying `NAs` can't be in row names, and the result is:

```
<NA>       100
1990-01-02 00:05:00  200
```

Obviously `xts` can't figure out what to do with the weird date there (midnight) and it won't coerce it.

If I add `tz="UTC"` to `as.POSIXct` it doesn't work. Additionally, `as.POSIXlt` doesnt change anything here either.

What can I do to coerce that midnight date to the correct format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two issues:

1) You cannot parse a date alone as POSIXct with a given format:

```
R> as.POSIXct(c("2017-01-02", "2017-01-03 04:05:06"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] NA                        "2017-01-03 04:05:06 CST"
R>
```

2) You can however use the `anytime()` function to do it:

```
R> anytime::anytime(c("2017-01-02", "2017-01-03 04:05:06"))
[1] "2017-01-02 00:00:00 CST" "2017-01-03 04:05:06 CST"
R>
```

Once you have a `POSIXct`, forming the `xts` is easy.

Also note that you have typos: you need a comma before the column indicator: `df[, "price"]`.

*Edit:* Getting a little tired of @42's comment about Gabor's (fine) solution "dominating" this one, so here's minimal benchmark:

```
R> library(microbenchmark)
R> v <- c("2017-01-02", "2017-01-03 04:05:06")
R> library(anytime)
R> print(microbenchmark(anytime(v), do.call("c", lapply(v, as.POSIXct))), digits=3)
Unit: microseconds
                                expr   min    lq  mean median    uq   max neval cld
                          anytime(v)  33.6  36.8  42.1   45.6  46.6  80.7   100  a 
 do.call("c", lapply(v, as.POSIXct)) 571.5 579.1 586.4  586.8 589.5 695.7   100   b
R>
```

so in short "not really". It is using only R Base, which is a plus, put it is a) harder read and understand, b) more limited as it deals with *exactly one* format (in ISO style) and c) it is about *thirteen times slower*.

Comment: Obligatory upvote for typo correction. `anytime` is quite neat. The best I could come up with in base R was `do.call(pmax, c(Map(as.POSIXct, dat["effective_date"], format=list("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%Y-%m-%d")), na.rm=TRUE) )`

Comment: I think G.Grothendeick's base solution would dominate this one.

Answer (score 7):

**1)** To get the `"POSIXct"` datetime vector try converting each datetime to `"POSIXct"` separately and then concatenate them together:

```
do.call("c", lapply(df$effective_date, as.POSIXct))
```

**2)** Another base solution that is even shorter and is also substantially faster is the following which relies on the fact that `as.POSIXct` will ignore junk at the end.

```
as.POSIXct(paste(df$effective, "00:00:00"))
```

Comment: Chapeau for using Base R, but it is a bunch slower (see my answer) and limited to ISO format on input.

Answer (score 3):

Most of `lubridate`'s parsing functions have a `truncated` parameter that takes a number indicating the number of elements that can be missing from the end. Missing elements will be replaced by zero.

Example with the data at hand:

```
lubridate::ymd_hms(c("2017-01-02", "2017-01-03 04:05:06"), truncated = 3)
## [1] "2017-01-02 00:00:00 UTC" "2017-01-03 04:05:06 UTC"
```

Comment: Well but that is still inferior to `anytime::anytime()` _as you have to supply the `truncated` argument_.

Comment: It requires a tiny bit more effort, yes, but it also gives you more control in case you want such dates to fail with a warning.

Comment: Well, zero is still less than one.  My solution is simply more generic as it will fail under fewer weird input scenarios, and requires less handholding and operator checks than this one. Oh well.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your larger point. Yes, `anytime` is impressive (as is your other work!), and requires very little from the user. That doesn't mean any other answer is invalid, though; SO is not a zero-sum game. Nor is package development, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the timestamps, preprocess with something like:

```
temp <- c("1990-01-01", "1990-01-02 00:05:00")

# match a date string at the end of string (indicated by $). Replace
# with the full string (indicated by \\1 and 00:00:00
temp2 <- gsub("(\\d{4}\\-\\d{2}\\-\\d{2}$)", "\\1 00:00:00", temp)

# [1] "1990-01-01 00:00:00" "1990-01-02 00:05:00"
```

Comment: That's pretty rough. I generally recommend against mucking with regexp when trying to parse dates, or transform them.  See my answer for a possible better way.